# How to Send Data to the Activity from a Foreground Service in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, interface, foreground-service

I need to find a way to send data from the foreground service to the main activity.
I'm considering using an interface in the foreground service for this purpose and seeking advice on its implementation.
Sending data to the activity can sometimes occur every few seconds and consecutively.
What do you think is the best and most efficient solution?

Solutions tried:

1. Create Static Variables and Methods: May lead to global state issues and memory leaks.
2. Create a Bound Service (Best for Two-way Communication): Uncertainty about its impact on background service running.
3. Use Intent to Send Data to Service: May not be optimal for frequent updates.
4. Use Broadcast Receiver: Not reliable for frequent and high-volume communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to use an `interface`. Define an interface like `DataUpdateListener` and create a private field with its own setter in your service.

in your main activity implement the interface using setter method, and whenever you want to publish data check if listener is not null, pass data to it.

```
public interface DataUpdateListener {
    void onDataUpdated(String data);
}
```

your need to change your service and add listeners:

```
public class YourService extends Service {

    private DataUpdateListener dataUpdateListener;

    // Instance of the local binder
    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();

    public void setDataUpdateListener(DataUpdateListener listener) {
        this.dataUpdateListener = listener;
    }

    private void sendDataToActivity(String data) {
        if (dataUpdateListener != null) {
            dataUpdateListener.onDataUpdated(data);
        }
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public YourService getService() {
            return YourService.this;
        }
    }


// Method to return the local binder
@Override
public IBinder onBind(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    super.onBind(intent);
    return binder;
}

}
```

also you need to define localbinder in your service:

in your main activity implement interface :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DataUpdateListener {


    @Override
    public void onDataUpdated(String data) {
        // handle the received data here
    }
}
```

and for binding interface to your service, you can do it like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DataUpdateListener {
    private YourService foregroundService;
    private boolean isServiceBound = false;


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (isServiceBound) {
            unbindService(serviceConnection);
            isServiceBound = false;
        }
    }

    private final ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            YourService.LocalBinder binder = (YourService.LocalBinder) iBinder;
            foregroundService = binder.getService();
            foregroundService.setDataUpdateListener(MainActivity.this);
            isServiceBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            foregroundService = null;
            isServiceBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now, how can I send the listener to the service? I currently call setDataUpdateListener in the onCreate() method of the MainActivity, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: I improved and completed my answer. You need to use `binders` along with a `ServiceConnection` to provide a way for clients like activities to interact with your service.

Comment: Let me a brief summary of the program's performance, When user clicks 'enable' button, I start a foreground service and display a notif. Even if the user closes the activity or app, the service continues to run in the background for hours. I need to send data every few seconds. Considering recent limitations in Android for foreground services, we had to resort to showing notifs. Do these restrictions also apply to bind services?
as I searched about bind service limitation, I found these:Service Not Guaranteed to Run Indefinitely and Communication Overhead. do you still offer me bind service?

Comment: If you want to send data continuously, you have two options. Using `foreground services` or using long time running tasks in `WorkManager`. If you want to use a service, you don't need to pass data to main activity. Create a handler with a runnable and use 'postDelayed' method to make sure it runs for long time, and send your data right away form your service.

Comment: Hi again. I have followed and overridden this function in the activity:

@Override
public void onDataUpdated(String data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onDataUpdated: ");
    binding.txtCharge.setText("blabla");
    Log.i(TAG, "onDataUpdated: " + binding.txtCharge.getText()); // the result is blabla
}

I have observed the first and second log messages in the Logcat, but my UI doesn't change anymore. Why is this happening? I wrapped the code within `runOnUiThread{}` but it still doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @FatimaNoori It seems you have some bug in other parts of your code. It should work as expected cause I'm using it in my projects